# Issue with scrolling in CollectionViewController - Swift

Tags: swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have an issue while scrolling horizontally inside a collectionViewController.

inside CellForItemA, i have the following, to draw on each horizontal Cell some lines:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let origine = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: CGFloat(cell.view.frame.height - 100))
    createTextLayer()
    showLoads(withOrigine: origine, cellForItemAt: indexPath, scale_H: scale_H, scale_V: scale_V, inView: cell.view)
    return cell
```

I am able to draw in each cell what ever I want, but the issue  is **sometime** what ever i draw for example in cell 1, it is showing the same in other cell.
This problem just appear when I move Cells quickly, as while doing this slowly I have no problem.

I tried to use prepareForReuse, willDisplay, but did not work.

Any advise how I can force the collectionViewTable to move just one cell in a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question already solved by Svein Halvor Halvorsen :

```
self.view.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible its the same cell, just reused by the system. Did you overwrite prepareForReuse and clean up the layer there?
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionreusableview

ReloadData is a function of the collectionView.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata

Comment: Thanks man for your reply, I tried prepareForReuse, but it was never called. I am not using the same Cell cause it is working some time okay. I am trying to look how I can force a cell to move only to next cell at once or if any idea how to make this issued solved would be appreciated.